# Is there a way to know why my Activity is being paused?

Tags: android

I have an app sort of like a browser, so I don't control the javascript that runs inside the pages, some of it might be looping like crazy and wasting battery. Also video or audio might be playing. I want all that to pause when the user leaves my app for another app. To do this I call `webView.onPause()` and `webView.pauseTimers()`. I tried only doing `onPause` but depending on what pages I had loaded my battery would still run down. As you might know, `pauseTimers` applies to all webviews so that means any ads I might have stop loading.

So for this reason I want to call `pauseTimers` only when my activity is being paused because the user is leaving the app, but not when the user is leaving my activity to go to another activity in my same app, because it might have ads.

So can I know when my activity is being paused because the user is leaving the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `Activity.onUserLeaveHint()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()

Comment: Interesting, that might be what I need, thank you.

Comment: Cool, I have added it as an answer for completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `Activity.onUserLeaveHint()`

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when the user presses the Home key, `onUserLeaveHint()` will be called, but when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be automatically brought to the foreground, `onUserLeaveHint()` will not be called on the activity being interrupted. In cases when it is invoked, this method is called right before the activity's `onPause()` callback.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-implementing the onPause() method? You can analyze the stacktrace in order to get some clues.

Also, this link might help you:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Answer (score -1):

Override the `onPause` method in your `actvity`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();

     //Do whatever you want to do 
 }
```